# Install NPM on linux

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

My purpose is to install angularjs !

For that i need => npm,so I want to install nodejs for having "NPM" but i have this error :

```
File "./configure", line 16, in <module>
from gyp.common import GetFlavor
File "./tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
import gyp.input
File "./tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 873
except ImportError as e:
```

Probably the problem is the version of python 2.5 : The problem is i don't have right to update python.

PLZ, how can i install npm on linux without Nodejs

Helps appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First update your system's package and make sure you have newest versions of packages and their dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install npm(and/or nodejs if needed)

```
sudo apt-get install npm nodejs
```

Finally, you may install angular with following command

```
npm install angular
```

FYI, [The best way to install npm is to install node using the node.js installer.](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/85484771375/how-to-install-npm) *npm is installed as part of node.*