# trying run angular 4 without deployment in server

Tags: angular

hello friends my question about **angular 4**, i create a new project in angular 4 and i want to run my angular 4 project in my server **without deployment** So please any one can help me in this.

Comment: Why you want to run a plain, unpacked Angular application on your server?

Comment: i want to edit angular 4 code on my server

Comment: Windows server or Linux?

Comment: linux is it possible to run without npm ?

Comment: I don't think so. You need npm for downloading the node_modules folder. maybe this link helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513877/install-npm-on-linux (That the question is about angularjs should not effect the approach)